# How to reenable default window decoration/theme of Ubuntu Kylin?

Tags: kylin

I am using Ubuntu Kylin 14.04.

Unfortunately I changed in the appearance settings program the window decoration/theme to "Ambiance" but the Kylin default one does not show in the list. How do I restore the Ubuntu Kylin default window decoration?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal by ctrl-alt-t, and then type the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ubuntukylin-theme
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ubuntukylin-icon-theme
```